# How create simple HelloWorld contract?

Tags: nodeos, cleos

I try example from book "Mastering EOS". I have written hello.cpp:

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>    
using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract]] hello: public contract {
public:
    using contract::contract;

    [[eosio::action]]
    void hi ( name user) {
        print ("Hello, ", user);
    }
};
```

(note: I changed eosy::action to eosio::action
After compiling eosio-cpp hello.cpp are warnings:

```
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
Warning, action <hi> does not have a ricardian contract
```

and appear files: hello.wasm and hello.abi
Next I try:

```
cleos create eosio account hello1 MY_PUBLC_KEY -p eosio@active
```

where paste key in place MY_PUBLC_KEY
is error: OwnerKey is required
Next I start nodeos and try

```
cleos set contract hello ~/CONTRACTS_DIR/hello1 -p hello.active
```

is error:

```
Publishing contract...
Failed to connect to nodeos at http://127.0.0.1:8888/; is nodeos running?
```

although nodeos is running.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether nodeos was run with the option `--plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin`. This option can be put in `config.ini` like `plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin`.

Comment: OK, but now is "Error 3120006: No available wallet \n Ensure that you have created a wallet and have it open". I am green is EOS and it may be related to previous command.

Comment: Run `cleos wallet unlock` with wallet password. If there's no jobs for 15 mins, wallet is locked automatically.

Comment: I have wallets: Scatter and Anchor with different passwords

Comment: No, cleos internally uses keosd (command-line wallet). You need to import default private key by `cleos wallet import 5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3`.

Comment: @Andrzej Welcome to the EOSIO stack exchange! If the answer from conr2d fixed your initial problem, it is helpful to other users if you mark the answer as "Accepted". If you have further problems with your wallet not being available, then please search the site for existing answer and then post a new question.